# About the exclusiveness of the cases of an if block

Tags: c++, c

I have a question about good coding practices. I understand the differences between doing an `if-else if` and multiple `if`s (that is, when a condition is met in an `if-else if`, the rest of the checks are skipped). I've found a piece of code along these lines:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
} else if (B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
}
```

I understand that this code won't check B == 7 if A == 5. The code works, so that means that B is only 7, if A is not 5, but I think this is just waiting to break when the code changes. What I would do is:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
    return or continue or break;
}
if (B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
    return or continue or break;
}
```

My question is, when I have multiple exclusive cases that depend on different, exclusive variables, what's the best way to tackle the flow control? I have the impression that the first code (with else ifs) depends a lot on other pieces of code to work, and that changes in other areas might break it. The second one seems to be a bit clunky. A switch could be a third option, but I would need to create another structure to hold the case and the logic to assign its value, and I think that it would be a bit clunky and counter-intuitive.

Comment: Why do you want "return or continue or break" in this code? If you don't have that the code works fine; if you do have it it's equivalent to the if..elseif case.  Not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: You need to break the execution if you don't want to do_something() AND do_something_else() when A == 5 AND B == 7. In the first piece of code, you guide the execution by making A == 5 or B == 7 in a different piece of code that assigns a value to only one of them, but I don't see that as a good practice, because they are different variables and the if-else-if is not exclusive. I wrote return or continue or break to indicate that I wanted to break the execution of that if, without explicitly indicating if my if block is in a function or a loop or a switch case.

Comment: Your first code (with `else if`) does achieve what you are describing in that comment. At most one of the blocks will be executed

Comment: First is clearly the winner since it doesn't make you break, continue, return if you don't have to.

Comment: I'm asking about code practices, about what's the best way to write an if case. I know that the code works, I'm asking if I need to rewrite it to make it more robust, and if so, what is in the opinion of more experienced coders the best way to tackle it.

The first piece of code guides the execution by checking if A == 7 and will never check for B, so it can be confusing for someone reviewing that code.

Comment: The first fragment is clear. You can have in real life a series of oracles, each saying "Absolutely Not" or "I'm busy -- go ask your mom". So both of these statements work logically on a different set of rules or variables, but affect your control flow.

Comment: In the above code, you may want to consider using `switch` and `case`.  This may be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked about "exclusive" cases, but the issue with the conditions `A == 5` and `B == 7` is that they are *not* exclusive; they are independent.

For full generality you may need to test and handle all four cases:

```
if(A == 5) {
    if(B == 7) {
        /* case 1 */
    } else {
        /* case 2 */
    }
} else {
    if(B == 7) {
        /* case 3 */
    } else {
        /* case 4 */
    }
}
```

This is the notorious "bushy" if/else block.  It's notorious because it can almost immediately become nearly impossible for a reader to follow, especially if the cases are involved, or more levels are introduced.  (I think most style guides will tell you never to use an if/else tree that's 3 or more levels deep.  I'd certainly say that.)

I have occasionally used these two alternatives:

(1) Fully decouple the cases:

```
if(A == 5 && B == 7) {
    /* case 1 */
} else if(A == 5 && B != 7) {
    /* case 2 */
} else if(A != 5 && B == 7) {
    /* case 3 */
} else if(A != 5 && B != 7) {
    /* case 4 */
} else {
    /* can't happen */
}
```

The point here is to make it maximally clear to a later reader exactly which conditions go with cases 1, 2, 3, and 4.  For this reason, you might as well list the last, `else if(A != 5 && B != 7)` case explicitly (as I've shown), even though by that point it's basically an "else".

(2) Contrive a "two level" switch.  I can't say this is a common technique; it has a whiff of being "too clever", but it's robust and readable, in its way:

```
#define PAIR(b1, b2) (((b1) << 8) | (b2))

switch(PAIR(A == 5), (B == 7)) {
    case PAIR(TRUE, TRUE):
        /* case 1 */
        break;

    case PAIR(TRUE, FALSE):
        /* case 2 */
        break;

    case PAIR(FALSE, TRUE):
        /* case 3 */
        break;

    case PAIR(FALSE, FALSE):
        /* case 4 */
        break;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this when the conditions are `A == 5` and `B == 7`, because when you're down in the switch, it's not obvious what "TRUE" and "FALSE" mean, but sometimes, this sort of thing can read cleanly.  It's also cleanly amenable to 3 or more levels of nesting, unlike "bushy" if/else trees, which as I said are notoriously unreadable.

Comment: I've used your `PAIR` technique a few times before, so _I_ [personally] don't consider it all that unusual. I've posted an answer that uses a different technique altogether to eliminate if/else ladders that you might find interesting. A side note: I'm doing +1 here, but if it were me, I would have added your second answer as an append to this answer (e.g. add line separator + "UPDATE:"). I wouldn't do it now since you already got +1 on the other, but ...

Comment: I think this gave me a new perspective on the subject, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I think you know, the two pieces of code are not equivalent.  (They're equivalent **IF** they both contain "return or continue or break", which makes the question more interesting, but that's a different answer.)

In general, which one you choose (or how you choose to rewrite it) has to depend on precisely what you want the program to do.

When you write

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
} else if (B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
}
```

you're additionally saying you want to `do_something_else` *only if* `A` is not equal to 5.  That might be just what you want, or it might be a bug.  If you wanted to achieve the same effect without an `else`, it would have to look like this:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
}

if (A != 5 && B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
}
```

The second piece of code you wrote in your question, on the other hand, has the potential to execute both `do_something` *and* `do_something_else`.

In general, it's best (clearest and least confusing) if all the conditions in an if/else chain test variations on the same condition, not some unusual mixture involving, for example, both `A` and `B`.

You use an if/else block when the alternatives are truly and deliberately exclusive, and when you want to emphasize this fact.  You might choose to use separate `if` blocks (not chained with `else`) when the alternatives are not exclusive, or when they're only coincidentally or accidentally exclusive.  For example, I have deliberately written code like

```
if(A == 5) {
    do_something();
}

if(A != 5) {
    do_some_unrelated_thing();
}
```

I might do this when the two things have nothing to do with each other, meaning that in some future revision of the program's logic, they might be not be exclusive after all.  Or, I might do this if `do_something` is not a single like, but is a long, elaborate block, at the end of which I'm concerned that the reader might not have remembered why we were or weren't doing something, and that on the other hand we might want to do something else.  For similar reasons, I've occasionally written

```
if(A == 5) {
    do_something();
}

if(A == 5) {
    do_some_unrelated_thing();
}
```

in the case that, again, the two things to be done had nothing to do with each other, and the reasons for doing them might diverge.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way of programming this,
while avoiding the assumption that either `A==5` or `B==7` is to consider all the four cases:

```
if ((A == 5) && (B == 7))
{
    do_somethingAB();
    /* or */
    do_somethingA();
    do_somethingB();
} else if (A == 5)
{
    do_somethingA();
} else if (B == 7)
{
    do_somethingB();
} else
{
    do_somethingNeither();
    /* or
       do nothing */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is now my third answer.  The fact that I keep misreading your question, and failing to grasp the essential point you're asking about, suggests that maybe I shouldn't be answering at all.]

I think the essential point you're asking about concerns the case where the cases are independent, *but* you get the *effect* of an `else` due to the fact that each clause contains a control-flow statement which "goes out": a `break`, or a `continue`, or a `return`, or something like that.

In this specific case, my preference today would be not to use the `else`.  When we write

```
if(A == 5) {
    do_something();
    return or continue or break;
}

if(B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
    return or continue or break;
}
```

it's clear that the two conditions have nothing to do with each other, other than that they're both cases that do something to "finish" the subtask being done, and leave the block of code that's responsible for performing that subtask.

When we write the two cases separately (without an else), we make clear not only that they're independent, but that they could be reordered, or that another case could be introduced in between them, etc.

But then again, *could* they be reordered?  How likely is it that both cases `A == 5` and `B == 7` will both be true?  And in that case, how important is it that `do_something` be done, as opposed to `do_something_else`?  If the two cases can't be reordered, if it would be wrong to test `B` first and maybe do `do_something_else`, I suppose the explicit `else` is preferable, to tie the two cases together and make even more clear the requirement that `A` be tested first.

Like any question of style, the arguments for and against this sort of thing end up being pretty subjective.  You're not likely to find a single, overwhelmingly convincing answer one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks Steve for persevering and answering three times to my question. I think the last one was the one that captured the meaning of my question the best. I don't want to break each condition in a tree, or cover all the possible cases, as it's not necessary, but I'll think a bit more about if the `elses` there will help the reader to understand the link between condition, or if it's better to split them.

Comment: I've come to this question after a couple of weeks to try to digest the information. As you say, the arguments for and against are totally subjective, and it really depends on what your code does and requires. Again, thanks for taking the time to answer (multiple times) to my question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to use a `do { ... } while (0);` technique.

Here is your original code:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
} else if (B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
}
```

Doing `else if` on the same line is [IMO] a bit of a hack because it hides the true indentation:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
}
else
    if (B == 7) {
        do_something_else();
    }
```

Using the aformentioned technique, which I've used quite a lot is:

```
do {
    if (A == 5) {
        do_something();
        break;
    }

    if (B == 7) {
        do_something_else();
        break;
    }
} while (0);
```

---

This becomes even more evident when we increase the number of levels in the if/else ladder:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
} else if (B == 7) {
    do_something_else();
} else if (C == 9) {
    do_something_else_again();
} else if (D == 3) {
    do_something_for_D();
}
```

Once again, this is indented to:

```
if (A == 5) {
    do_something();
}
else
    if (B == 7) {
        do_something_else();
    }
    else
        if (C == 9) {
            do_something_else_again();
        }
        else
            if (D == 3) {
                do_something_for_D();
            }
```

Using the `do/while/0` block, we get something that is simpler/cleaner:

```
do {
    if (A == 5) {
        do_something();
        break;
    }

    if (B == 7) {
        do_something_else();
        break;
    }

    if (C == 9) {
        do_something_else_again();
        break;
    }

    if (D == 3) {
        do_something_for_D();
        break;
    }
} while (0);
```

---

*Note:* I've been programming in `c` for 35+ years, and I've yet to find a case where a more standard use of `do/while` (e.g. `do { ... } while (<cond>)`) can't be replaced more cleanly/effectively with either a standard `for` or `while` loop. Some languages don't even have a `do/while` loop. Thus, I consider the `do` loop to be available for reuse.

---

Another use of `do/while/0` is to allow things defined by a preprocessor macro to appear as a single block:

```
#define ABORTME(msg_) \
    do { \
        printf(stderr,"ABORT: %s (at line %d)\n",msg_,__LINE__); \
        dump_some_state_data(); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

if (some_error_condition)
    ABORTME("some_error_condition");
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, I'll give it a go and see how it looks like in terms of readability. Thanks!