# circular buffer with read only access from reader

Tags: c, circular-buffer

I have a problem with a circular buffer I want to build where the reader only has read-only access. In order to achieve a smooth rollover, I have the writer to set an id in iterator+1 of the rollover data structure to 0 for which I check in with the reader. My algorith seems to work fine until the first roll over, then for some reason, the resder will read 0 from the id which the writer obviously has set.
i have some compileable example code to demonstrate the problem right here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_ALM 5
#define ERROR   -1
#define OK      0

//even IDs = alarm active
//odd IDs  = alarm clear
enum alarmid {
    BFD_ACT     = 0x02,
    BFD_CLR     = 0x03,
    LOS_ACT     = 0x0C
};
typedef struct alarm_s {
    long timestamp;
    int alarmid;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
}alarm_t;
int alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2);
int next_alarm_read(alarm_t *res);
void *alarm_reader(void *arg);

static alarm_t *roller;
pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int main (void)
{
    int i =0;
    alarm_t dat;
    pthread_t reader;
    int ret;

    roller = calloc(NUM_ALM,sizeof(alarm_t));
    printf("allocated memory: %lukB\n",(sizeof(alarm_t)*NUM_ALM)/1024);

    for (i = 1; i< NUM_ALM; i++){
        alarm_add(LOS_ACT,i,0);
    }
    ret = pthread_create(&reader,NULL,alarm_reader,NULL);
    if (ret){
        printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",ret);
        return ERROR;
    }
    sleep(1);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR,8,0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT,8,0);

    pthread_join(reader,NULL);
}

void *alarm_reader(void *arg)
{
    static alarm_t dat={0};
    int err = 0;
    while(err <= 2)
    {
        if (next_alarm_read(&dat)== OK)
            printf("read alarm id %d, arg1 %d,arg2 %d\n",dat.alarmid,dat.arg1,dat.arg2);
        else{
            printf("alarm_reader() next_alarm_read() returned ERROR, wait\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

            err++;
        }
    }
    printf("alarm_reader exit!\n");
}
int alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    static int i = 0;
    alarm_t dat={0};
    if (i<NUM_ALM){
        dat.timestamp = time(NULL);
        dat.alarmid = id;
        dat.arg1 = arg1;
        dat.arg2 = arg2;

        if (&roller[i]){
            memcpy(&roller[i],&dat,sizeof(alarm_t));
            if (i+1<NUM_ALM)
                roller[i+1].alarmid = 0;
            else
                roller[0].alarmid = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
            printf("added id %d, arg1 %d, arg2 %d @%d\n",roller[i].alarmid,roller[i].arg1,roller[i].arg2,i);
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int next_alarm_read(alarm_t *res)
{
    static int i = 0;
    static long prev_time = 0;
    if (!res)
        return ERROR;

    if (i<NUM_ALM)
    {
        if (roller[i].alarmid!=0){
            printf("next_alarm_read() reading @%d\n",i);
            res->timestamp = roller[i].timestamp;
            res->alarmid = roller[i].alarmid;
            res->arg1 = roller[i].arg1;
            res->arg2 = roller[i].arg2;
            prev_time = roller[i].timestamp;
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("next_alarm_read() @%d is %d,return ERROR\n",i,roller[i].alarmid);

            return ERROR;
        }
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Where the outpout looks like:

```
added id 12, arg1 1, arg2 0 @0
added id 12, arg1 2, arg2 0 @1
added id 12, arg1 3, arg2 0 @2
added id 12, arg1 4, arg2 0 @3
next_alarm_read() reading @0
read alarm id 12, arg1 1,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() reading @1
read alarm id 12, arg1 2,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() reading @2
read alarm id 12, arg1 3,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() reading @3
read alarm id 12, arg1 4,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() @4 is 0,return ERROR
alarm_reader() next_alarm_read() returned ERROR, wait
added id 2, arg1 8, arg2 0 @4
added id 2, arg1 8, arg2 0 @0
added id 2, arg1 8, arg2 0 @1
added id 3, arg1 8, arg2 0 @2
added id 3, arg1 8, arg2 0 @3
added id 3, arg1 8, arg2 0 @4
added id 2, arg1 8, arg2 0 @0
next_alarm_read() reading @4
read alarm id 3, arg1 8,arg2 0
read alarm id 3, arg1 8,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() reading @0
read alarm id 2, arg1 8,arg2 0
next_alarm_read() @1 is 0,return ERROR
alarm_reader() next_alarm_read() returned ERROR, wait
```

the bottom print for `next_alarm_read() @1 is 0,return ERROR` is wrong, the id should be 2. Why does this not work as intended I'nm wondering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

I'm not sure what `if (&roller[i])` is supposed to do/mean.

The `sleep` in `main` isn't really needed and I suspect it's an attempt to ameliorate the other issues below.

`alarm_add` will drop an entry at the rollover point.

Also, it may overrun the reader and overwrite entries before the reader can see the entries (i.e. a race condition).

The reader and writer both need to see each others current queue indexes (i.e. they shouldn't be function scoped `static`) to prevent overrun/race

There should be *two* condition variables and not just one:

1. The writer detects the queue is full and needs to block until the reader has drained an entry
2. The reader detects an empty queue and needs to block until the writer adds a new entry

---

Here's a refactored version of your code that should address these issues. I've added some debug code. It may not be perfect [and may err on the side of conservatism], but it should get you a bit further [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_ALM 5
#define ERROR   -1
#define OK      0

double tvzero;

//even IDs = alarm active
//odd IDs  = alarm clear
enum alarmid {
    BFD_ACT = 0x02,
    BFD_CLR = 0x03,
    LOS_ACT = 0x0C
};

typedef struct alarm_s {
    long timestamp;
    int alarmid;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
} alarm_t;

void alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2);
int next_alarm_read(alarm_t * res);
void *alarm_reader(void *arg);

static alarm_t *roller;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// reader variables
pthread_cond_t cv_notempty;             // writer signals when queue not empty
volatile int need_notempty;             // reader sets this before waiting
volatile int idxdeq;                    // reader's queue index

// writer variables
pthread_cond_t cv_notfull;              // reader signals when queue not full
volatile int need_notfull;              // writer sets this before waiting
volatile int idxenq;                    // writer's queue index

volatile int stopall;

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tvzero;

    return sec;
}

#define DBG(_reason) \
    dbg(_reason)

void
dbg(const char *reason)
{
    double tvnow;

    tvnow = tvgetf();
    printf("[%.9f] %s\n",tvnow,reason);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    pthread_t reader;
    int ret;

    tvzero = tvgetf();

    roller = calloc(NUM_ALM, sizeof(alarm_t));
    printf("allocated memory: %lukB\n", (sizeof(alarm_t) * NUM_ALM) / 1024);

    // NOTE: queuing more than a full queue here will cause writer to block
    // forever because reader is not yet started
    for (i = 1; i < NUM_ALM; i++) {
        alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, alarm_reader, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n", ret);
        return ERROR;
    }

#if 0
    sleep(1);
#endif

    alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
    alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);

    // tell reader that all items are queued and it should stop when it
    // processes the final item
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    stopall = 1;
    if (need_notempty)
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notempty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_join(reader, NULL);

    return 0;
}

// RETURNS: queue index to process (-1=empty)
int
queue_notempty(void)
{
    int curidx;

    do {
        curidx = idxdeq;

        // queue is empty
        if (curidx == idxenq) {
            curidx = -1;
            break;
        }

        // advance dequeue index
        idxdeq += 1;
        idxdeq %= NUM_ALM;
    } while (0);

    return curidx;
}

// RETURNS: queue index to use (-1=full)
int
queue_notfull(void)
{
    int nxtidx;
    int curidx;

    do {
        // get current index
        curidx = idxenq;

        // advance to next slot (wrapping if necessary)
        nxtidx = curidx;
        nxtidx += 1;
        nxtidx %= NUM_ALM;

        // queue is full
        if (nxtidx == idxdeq) {
            curidx = -1;
            break;
        }

        // store back adjusted index
        idxenq = nxtidx;
    } while (0);

    return curidx;
}

void *
alarm_reader(void *arg)
{
    alarm_t dat = { 0 };

    while (1) {
        if (next_alarm_read(&dat))
            break;
        printf("read alarm id %d, arg1 %d,arg2 %d\n",
            dat.alarmid, dat.arg1, dat.arg2);
    }

    printf("alarm_reader exit!\n");

    return (void *) 0;
}

void
alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    int curidx;
    alarm_t *rol;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (1) {
        curidx = queue_notfull();

        // have an open slot -- store item into it
        if (curidx >= 0) {
            rol = &roller[curidx];

            rol->timestamp = time(NULL);
            rol->alarmid = id;
            rol->arg1 = arg1;
            rol->arg2 = arg2;

            printf("added id %d, arg1 %d, arg2 %d @%d\n",
                rol->alarmid, rol->arg1, rol->arg2, curidx);

            // unblock reader if necessary
            if (need_notempty) {
                DBG("writer signal notempty");
                need_notempty = 0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notempty);
            }

            break;
        }

        // queue is full -- wait for reader to free up some space
        DBG("writer need_notfull");
        need_notfull = 1;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv_notfull,&mutex);
        DBG("writer wakeup");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

// RETURNS: 1=stop, 0=normal
int
next_alarm_read(alarm_t *res)
{
    //static long prev_time = 0;
    int curidx;
    alarm_t *rol;
    int stopflg = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (1) {
        curidx = queue_notempty();

        // queue has an entry -- process it
        if (curidx >= 0) {
            rol = &roller[curidx];

            printf("next_alarm_read() reading @%d\n", curidx);
            *res = *rol;
            //prev_time = rol->timestamp;

            // if writer is waiting/blocking, wake it up because we just
            // freed up a queue slot
            if (need_notfull) {
                DBG("reader signal notfull");
                need_notfull = 0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notfull);
            }

            break;
        }

        // stop when master has enqueued everything
        stopflg = stopall;
        if (stopflg)
            break;

        // queue is empty -- we must wait for writer to add something
        DBG("reader need_notempty");
        need_notempty = 1;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv_notempty,&mutex);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return stopflg;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I don't understand the do while(0); "loops" in the two Q functions, can you elaboratea little, please?

The `do while(0)` is a technique that I use a lot to replace if/else ladder logic. I didn't invent it [it's discussed in some style guides, notably, "Code Complete"], but a lot of people that I've shown it to seem to like it. See my answer: [About the exclusiveness of the cases of an if block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656651/about-the-exclusiveness-of-the-cases-of-an-if-block/50685506#50685506) for a better explanation.

> And I guessx what my initrial post didn't include is: the master should be able to enqueue things on an ongoing basis, there's no `stopall` and the reader should start reading as soon as something is available.

Actually, I *did* realize that and the code I posted allows for that.

You may want to issue the `pthread_create` *before* enqueuing any messages to prevent the potential deadlock I mentioned in the code comments.

> A fix for this would be to remove `stopall`, the `pthread_cond-signal()` (from main) is already done inside `alarm_add()` so this should work fine.

The `stopall` is *not* to synchronize against overflow/underflow. It is merely if the writer (main thread) wants the receiver/thread to finish up and stop cleanly. It's more like a way to send an "EOF" condition to the reader.

If your application is to run "forever", you can remove the `stopall`.

Or, a cleaner way to signal "EOF": the main thread could enqueue a special "stop" message (e.g. a message with a timestamp of -1) to tell the receiver that no more messages will be sent *ever* and we wish to terminate the program.

---

What I suggest is that you add a "diagnostic mode" to validate your program:

Have the `main` do the `pthread_create` and then do:

```
    for (i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
        alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
    }
```

The reader should examine the `arg1` values that come in. They should *increment* as above. If they don't, there is a logic error or race condition.

---

Here is an updated version of my code with a `-D` option for a diagnostic/unit test mode. Note that all printing is disabled to allow it to run at extreme speed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_ALM 5
#define ERROR   -1
#define OK      0

int opt_diag;
double tvzero;

//even IDs = alarm active
//odd IDs  = alarm clear
enum alarmid {
    BFD_ACT = 0x02,
    BFD_CLR = 0x03,
    LOS_ACT = 0x0C
};

typedef struct alarm_s {
    long timestamp;
    int alarmid;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
} alarm_t;

void alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2);
int next_alarm_read(alarm_t * res);
void *alarm_reader(void *arg);

static alarm_t *roller;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// reader variables
pthread_cond_t cv_notempty;             // writer signals when queue not empty
volatile int need_notempty;             // reader sets this before waiting
volatile int idxdeq;                    // reader's queue index

// writer variables
pthread_cond_t cv_notfull;              // reader signals when queue not full
volatile int need_notfull;              // writer sets this before waiting
volatile int idxenq;                    // writer's queue index

volatile int stopall;

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tvzero;

    return sec;
}

#define prtf(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_diag) \
            break; \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

#define DBG(_reason) \
    dbg(_reason)

void
dbg(const char *reason)
{
    double tvnow;

    if (! opt_diag) {
        tvnow = tvgetf();
        printf("[%.9f] %s\n",tvnow,reason);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *cp;
    pthread_t reader;
    int ret;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'D':
            cp += 2;
            opt_diag = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 10000000;
            break;
        }
    }

    tvzero = tvgetf();

    roller = calloc(NUM_ALM, sizeof(alarm_t));
    printf("allocated memory: %lukB\n", (sizeof(alarm_t) * NUM_ALM) / 1024);

    // NOTE: queuing more than a full queue here will cause writer to block
    // forever because reader is not yet started
    if (! opt_diag) {
        for (i = 1; i < NUM_ALM; i++) {
            alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
        }
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, alarm_reader, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n", ret);
        return ERROR;
    }

#if 0
    sleep(1);
#endif

    if (opt_diag) {
        for (i = 1; i < opt_diag; i++) {
            alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
        }
    }
    else {
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    }

    // tell reader that all items are queued and it should stop when it
    // processes the final item
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    stopall = 1;
    if (need_notempty)
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notempty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_join(reader, NULL);

    return 0;
}

// RETURNS: queue index to process (-1=empty)
int
queue_notempty(void)
{
    int curidx;

    do {
        curidx = idxdeq;

        // queue is empty
        if (curidx == idxenq) {
            curidx = -1;
            break;
        }

        // advance dequeue index
        idxdeq += 1;
        idxdeq %= NUM_ALM;
    } while (0);

    return curidx;
}

// RETURNS: queue index to use (-1=full)
int
queue_notfull(void)
{
    int nxtidx;
    int curidx;

    do {
        // get current index
        curidx = idxenq;

        // advance to next slot (wrapping if necessary)
        nxtidx = curidx;
        nxtidx += 1;
        nxtidx %= NUM_ALM;

        // queue is full
        if (nxtidx == idxdeq) {
            curidx = -1;
            break;
        }

        // store back adjusted index
        idxenq = nxtidx;
    } while (0);

    return curidx;
}

void *
alarm_reader(void *arg)
{
    alarm_t dat = { 0 };
    static int expval = 1;

    while (1) {
        if (next_alarm_read(&dat))
            break;

        if (opt_diag) {
            if (dat.arg1 != expval) {
                printf("expected: %d got %d\n",expval,dat.arg1);
                exit(1);
            }
            ++expval;
        }

        prtf("read alarm id %d, arg1 %d,arg2 %d\n",
            dat.alarmid, dat.arg1, dat.arg2);
    }

    printf("alarm_reader exit!\n");

    return (void *) 0;
}

void
alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    int curidx;
    alarm_t *rol;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (1) {
        curidx = queue_notfull();

        // have an open slot -- store item into it
        if (curidx >= 0) {
            rol = &roller[curidx];

            rol->timestamp = time(NULL);
            rol->alarmid = id;
            rol->arg1 = arg1;
            rol->arg2 = arg2;

            prtf("added id %d, arg1 %d, arg2 %d @%d\n",
                rol->alarmid, rol->arg1, rol->arg2, curidx);

            // unblock reader if necessary
            if (need_notempty) {
                DBG("writer signal notempty");
                need_notempty = 0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notempty);
            }

            break;
        }

        // queue is full -- wait for reader to free up some space
        DBG("writer need_notfull");
        need_notfull = 1;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv_notfull,&mutex);
        DBG("writer wakeup");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

// RETURNS: 1=stop, 0=normal
int
next_alarm_read(alarm_t *res)
{
    //static long prev_time = 0;
    int curidx;
    alarm_t *rol;
    int stopflg = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    while (1) {
        curidx = queue_notempty();

        // queue has an entry -- process it
        if (curidx >= 0) {
            rol = &roller[curidx];

            prtf("next_alarm_read() reading @%d\n", curidx);
            *res = *rol;
            //prev_time = rol->timestamp;

            // if writer is waiting/blocking, wake it up because we just
            // freed up a queue slot
            if (need_notfull) {
                DBG("reader signal notfull");
                need_notfull = 0;
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv_notfull);
            }

            break;
        }

        // stop when master has enqueued everything
        stopflg = stopall;
        if (stopflg)
            break;

        // queue is empty -- we must wait for writer to add something
        DBG("reader need_notempty");
        need_notempty = 1;
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv_notempty,&mutex);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return stopflg;
}
```

---

Here is a version of your original code with the diagnostic option added:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int opt_diag;

#define NUM_ALM 5
#define ERROR   -1
#define OK      0

//even IDs = alarm active
//odd IDs  = alarm clear
enum alarmid {
    BFD_ACT = 0x02,
    BFD_CLR = 0x03,
    LOS_ACT = 0x0C
};
typedef struct alarm_s {
    long timestamp;
    int alarmid;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
} alarm_t;
int alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2);
int next_alarm_read(alarm_t * res);
void *alarm_reader(void *arg);

static alarm_t *roller;
pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

#define prtf(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_diag) \
            break; \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *cp;
    pthread_t reader;
    int ret;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'D':
            cp += 2;
            opt_diag = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 10000000;
            break;
        }
    }

    roller = calloc(NUM_ALM, sizeof(alarm_t));
    printf("allocated memory: %lukB\n", (sizeof(alarm_t) * NUM_ALM) / 1024);

    if (! opt_diag) {
        for (i = 1; i < NUM_ALM; i++) {
            alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
        }
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&reader, NULL, alarm_reader, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n", ret);
        return ERROR;
    }

    if (opt_diag) {
        for (i = 1; i < opt_diag; i++) {
            alarm_add(LOS_ACT, i, 0);
        }
    }
    else {
        sleep(1);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_CLR, 8, 0);
        alarm_add(BFD_ACT, 8, 0);
    }

    pthread_join(reader, NULL);
}

void *
alarm_reader(void *arg)
{
    static alarm_t dat = { 0 };
    int expval = 1;
    int err = 0;

    while (err <= 2) {
        if (next_alarm_read(&dat) == OK) {
            prtf("read alarm id %d, arg1 %d,arg2 %d\n", dat.alarmid, dat.arg1, dat.arg2);
            if (opt_diag) {
                if (dat.arg1 != expval) {
                    printf("expected: %d got %d\n",expval,dat.arg1);
                    exit(1);
                }
                ++expval;
            }
        }
        else {
            prtf("alarm_reader() next_alarm_read() returned ERROR, wait\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

            err++;
        }
    }
    printf("alarm_reader exit!\n");

    return (void *) 0;
}

int
alarm_add(int id, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    static int i = 0;
    alarm_t dat = { 0 };
    if (i < NUM_ALM) {
        dat.timestamp = time(NULL);
        dat.alarmid = id;
        dat.arg1 = arg1;
        dat.arg2 = arg2;

        if (&roller[i]) {
            memcpy(&roller[i], &dat, sizeof(alarm_t));
            if (i + 1 < NUM_ALM)
                roller[i + 1].alarmid = 0;
            else
                roller[0].alarmid = 0;
            pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
            prtf("added id %d, arg1 %d, arg2 %d @%d\n", roller[i].alarmid, roller[i].arg1, roller[i].arg2, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
next_alarm_read(alarm_t * res)
{
    static int i = 0;
    //static long prev_time = 0;

    if (!res)
        return ERROR;

    if (i < NUM_ALM) {
        if (roller[i].alarmid != 0) {
            prtf("next_alarm_read() reading @%d\n", i);
            res->timestamp = roller[i].timestamp;
            res->alarmid = roller[i].alarmid;
            res->arg1 = roller[i].arg1;
            res->arg2 = roller[i].arg2;
            //prev_time = roller[i].timestamp;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            prtf("next_alarm_read() @%d is %d,return ERROR\n", i, roller[i].alarmid);

            return ERROR;
        }
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: oh wow! Great thanks!  Let me ponder this a bit! First awesome thing I found is: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` - I dind't know about it, cool!

Comment: I don't understand the `do while(0);` "loops" in the two Q functions, can you elaboratea little, please?

Comment: And I guessx what my initrial post didn't include is: the master should be able to enqueue things on an ongoing basis, there's no `stopall` and the reader should start reading as soon as something is available. A fix for this would be to remove `stopall`, the `pthread_cond-signal()`(from main) is already done inside `alarm_add()` so this should work fine.

Comment: The `do while(0)` is a technique that I use a lot to replace `if/else` ladder logic. I didn't invent it, but a lot of people that I've shown it to seem to like it. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50685506/5382650 for a better explanation