# the time complexity of my code is O(n+m)?

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

My code is below :

```
double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size){
    int* new = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (nums1Size+nums2Size));
    int i = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    if(nums1Size+nums2Size == 1){
        if(nums1Size == 1)
            return *nums1;
        else
            return *nums2;
    }
    else if(nums1Size == 0){
        if((nums2Size & 0x1) == 0)
            return (double)(nums2[nums2Size/2-1]+nums2[nums2Size/2])/2;
        else
            return (double)nums2[nums2Size/2];
    }
    else if(nums2Size == 0){
        if((nums1Size & 0x1) == 0)
            return (double)(nums1[nums1Size/2-1]+nums1[nums1Size/2])/2;
        else
            return (double)nums1[nums1Size/2];
    }


   while(i != (nums1Size+nums2Size))
   {

       if((nums1[count1 == nums1Size ? count1-1:count1] > nums2[count2 == nums2Size ? count2-1:count2] 
           && (count2) != nums2Size)
          || (count1) == nums1Size)
       {
           *(new+i) = *(nums2+count2);
           count2++;
       }
       else{
           *(new+i) = *(nums1+count1);
           count1++;

       }
       i++;
   }   

    if(((nums1Size+nums2Size) & 0x1) == 0){
        return (double)(new[(nums1Size+nums2Size)/2 - 1] + new[(nums1Size+nums2Size)/2]) / 2;
    }
    else
        return (double)new[(nums1Size+nums2Size)/2];
}
```

And below is the submissions's runtime distribution on Leetcode :

[image]

**The Question is,** even if there are a lot of submitted codes with O(log (m+n)) in C but I think my code's Time complexity is O(m+n). so it doesn't make sense that my code is top 2% on Leetcode according to the distribution graph. of course linear is faster than log to a small amount of inputs but the test-cases are enough big to get beaten by O(log (m+n)). I don't know why my code get passed with that rate.

*will greatly appreciate your comments!*

Comment: `&nums2[count2]-&nums2[0]` is just `count2`..

Comment: ha right. thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: I do not understand your concern. Why do you think submissions on leetcode will be ordered depending on distribution of code? What is the reasoning that goes from "runtime of my code beats 98% code submissions on lettcode" to "it doesn't make sense". Why and how would be complexity of your code related to runtime speed of code of _other_ subsmissions? Are you somehow assuming, that others have to write faster code than you? You only found out that 98% _submissions to leetcode_ are slower then you - that means something about users of leetcode, not your code.

Comment: @KamilCuk *1. Why do you think submissions on leetcode will be ordered depending on distribution of code?* When my submitted code turns out to be correct, Leetcode says like "Runtime: 8 ms, faster than 98.32% of C online submissions for Median of Two Sorted Arrays."  | *2. Why and how would be complexity of your code related to runtime speed of code of other subsmissions? The complexity of my code is related to the runtime speed of code of mine, and the same goes for others code. so I'm saying why my O(m+n) code got better speed(they say "Faster") than the others O(log(m+n)) code.* | *3.* noup

Comment: But why do you think others have faster code? I believe 98% subsmission are _at best_ - pack both arrays into one big array, `qsort` it, print. Note that your code doesn't free allocated memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk: OP hypothesizes that a considerable number of submissions, at least a few percent, would use code with O(log(m+n)) and therefore would execute faster than their O(m+n) code. Leetcode’s reported percentile for their code contradicts this conclusion, and OP therefore would like to know whether their hypothesis about the number of submissions using O(log(m+n)) code is wrong, whether their reasoning that their O(m+n) code is necessarily wrong, or whether something in their reasoning is wrong.

Comment: @KamilCuk in almost every problems on Leetcode including the problem above, we are told not to use free() for allocated memory. and the answer for the first question is yeah that might be one of the reasons.

Comment: _Side note:_ You allocate `new` at the start of the function. If any of the "early escape" `return` statements are executed, you'll leak memory.

Comment: @CraigEstey So do I have to put free() in every return statement? or how can i fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From my top comment:* You allocate `new` at the start of the function. If any of the "early escape" `return` statements are executed, you'll leak memory.

> So do I have to put `free()` in every `return` statement? or how can i fix my code?

Don't do the `malloc` until *after* the top block of early escapes.

And, do the `free` at the bottom. To do this, you'll need an extra variable to hold the return value so you can safely do the `free(new)` (e.g. `double retval;`)

*Side note:* It's usually cleaner to replace (e.g.) `*(new + i)` with `new[i]`. Also, holding the code to <= 80 chars / line is also a good style.

---

Here's one way to fix your code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
double
findMedianSortedArrays(int *nums1, int nums1Size, int *nums2, int nums2Size)
{
    int *new;
    int i;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    double retval;

    if (nums1Size + nums2Size == 1) {
        if (nums1Size == 1)
            return *nums1;
        else
            return *nums2;
    }

    if (nums1Size == 0) {
        if ((nums2Size & 0x1) == 0)
            return (double) (nums2[nums2Size / 2 - 1] +
                nums2[nums2Size / 2]) / 2;
        else
            return nums2[nums2Size / 2];
    }

    if (nums2Size == 0) {
        if ((nums1Size & 0x1) == 0)
            return (double) (nums1[nums1Size / 2 - 1] +
                nums1[nums1Size / 2]) / 2;
        else
            return (double) nums1[nums1Size / 2];
    }

    // allocate this only when you're sure you'll use it
    new = malloc(sizeof(int) * (nums1Size + nums2Size));

    for (i = 0;  i != (nums1Size + nums2Size);  ++i) {
        if ((nums1[count1 == nums1Size ? count1 - 1 : count1] >
            nums2[count2 == nums2Size ? count2 - 1 : count2] &&
                (count2) != nums2Size)
            || (count1) == nums1Size) {
            new[i] = nums2[count2];
            count2++;
        }
        else {
            new[i] = nums1[count1];
            count1++;
        }
    }

    if (((nums1Size + nums2Size) & 0x1) == 0) {
        retval = (double) (new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2 - 1] +
            new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2]) / 2;
    }
    else
        retval = (double) new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2];

    free(new);

    return retval;
}
```

---

But, personally, I dislike multiple `return` statements in a function. It's harder to debug [using `gdb`] because you'd have to set a breakpoint on *each* `return`.

Here's a version that uses a `do { ... } while (0);` as a "once through" loop that allows us to eliminate the `if/else` "ladder" logic [which I also personally dislike] and have only a *single* `return` at the bottom. YMMV ...

```
double
findMedianSortedArrays(int *nums1, int nums1Size, int *nums2, int nums2Size)
{
    int *new = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    double retval;

    do {
        if (nums1Size + nums2Size == 1) {
            if (nums1Size == 1)
                retval = *nums1;
            else
                retval = *nums2;
            break;
        }

        if (nums1Size == 0) {
            if ((nums2Size & 0x1) == 0)
                retval = (double) (nums2[nums2Size / 2 - 1] +
                    nums2[nums2Size / 2]) / 2;
            else
                retval = nums2[nums2Size / 2];
            break;
        }

        if (nums2Size == 0) {
            if ((nums1Size & 0x1) == 0)
                retval = (double) (nums1[nums1Size / 2 - 1] +
                    nums1[nums1Size / 2]) / 2;
            else
                retval = (double) nums1[nums1Size / 2];
            break;
        }

        // allocate this only when you're sure you'll use it
        new = malloc(sizeof(int) * (nums1Size + nums2Size));

        for (;  i != (nums1Size + nums2Size);  ++i) {
            if ((nums1[count1 == nums1Size ? count1 - 1 : count1] >
                nums2[count2 == nums2Size ? count2 - 1 : count2] &&
                    (count2) != nums2Size)
                || (count1) == nums1Size) {
                new[i] = nums2[count2];
                count2++;
            }
            else {
                new[i] = nums1[count1];
                count1++;
            }
        }

        if (((nums1Size + nums2Size) & 0x1) == 0) {
            retval = (double) (new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2 - 1] +
                new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2]) / 2;
        }
        else
            retval = (double) new[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2];
    } while (0);

    if (new != NULL)
        free(new);

    return retval;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> thanks! I understood. your code is more clear than mine for real!. but what do you think about the performance between them? ( `if/else` and `do{...}while(0))`. because if we assume the compiler would work as we generally expect, `if/else` is faster than if if which is in `do{...}` in the revised code. thanks a lot again!

Actually, if we disassemble both versions [compiled with `-O2`], the `do/while` version is 4 assembly instructions shorter.

But, in order to tune it, you have to measure it.

The optimizer will pretty much make them similar.

The main bulk of the time of the function is spent in the `for` loop, which is the same for both. The speed of the loop dwarfs any extra overhead of `do/while` which might be an assembler instruction or two [but, again the `do/while` has fewer instructions].

So, tuning/optimizing the prolog/epilog code of the function isn't [usually] worth it. Speeding up the loop is.

To tune/optimize, either do profiling to determine where the code spends the most amount of time [or for something this simple, it's obviously the loop], or add timestamping and get elapsed time on the function [or various subparts].

As I mentioned, it's hard to add a breakpoint for a function that has multiple `return` statements.

Also, sometimes you can't attach a debugger. Or, it's difficult to find a *meaningful* place to put a breakpoint. For example, if you have a program that runs fine for (e.g.) days, and then aborts after (e.g.) 63 hours, you may need to do internal benchmarking and `printf` style debugging:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprint(_fmt) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprint(_fmt) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

double
findMedianSortedArrays(int *nums1, int nums1Size, int *nums2, int nums2Size)
{
    double retval;

    dbgprint("findMedianSortedArrays: ENTER nums1Size=%d nums2Size=%d\n",
        nums1Size,nums2Size);

    // ... the code

    dbgprint("findMediaSortedArrays: EXIT retval=%g\n",retval);

    return retval;
}
```

It's much easier to insert the debug print statements with the second version.

BTW, I do this sort of thing all the time. And, one of my fortes is fast code and performance improvement [as I do a lot of realtime coding].

Comment: thanks! this is a huge help for me to revise my code. But I'm wondering why ```do{...}while(0)``` eliminates ```if/else``` ladder from the original code? cause in the sense of ```if/else```, it doesn't look different to me.

Comment: From your original at the top, the if/else ladder (e.g. `else if (...)`). Here's a answer of mine that explains my notion in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656651/about-the-exclusiveness-of-the-cases-of-an-if-block/50685506#50685506

Comment: thanks! I understood. your code is more clear than mine for real!. but what do you think about the performance between them? ( ```if/else``` and ```do{...}while(0)```). because if we assume the compiler would work as we generally expect, ```if/else``` is faster than ```if if``` which is in do{...} in the revised code. thanks a lot again!