# Dynamic Arrays creation in C, function to create dynamic arrays

Tags: c, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I am new to C and had a question about dynamic arrays.

I am building a game so that when the user enters 6 numbers so that it matches the 6 random numbers that the code generates, the user wins.

I am trying to create a dynamic array to store the user's guesses until the user gets the answer correctly. However, I am unsure of how that would work. Would I create a function so that whenever the user gets an answer wrong, I call the function to create a new dynamic array to store the user's guesses?

Comment: For some examples of dynamic arrays, see my answers: [C Programming: Reading data from a file, dynamically allocating memory, placing contents in struct array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66592519/5382650) and [Creation of Dynamic Array of Strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73737192/5382650)

Comment: Do you mean "dynamically allocated" arrays? C does not have a built-in extensible array type.

Comment: It's always worth asking yourself if there is an upper bound on the number of elements you wish to store. Sometimes it's not worth the hassle of using a dynamic, growable data structure.

Comment: Write singly/doubly linked-list according to your need

Comment: Why do you need dynamic memory? This sounds like a solid case for a fixed maximum number of tries. Or will the game run for all eternity until they guess the right numbers?

Comment: Yes it will run for all eternity until they guess the right numbers @Lundin.

Answer (score 0):

What does a "vector" that can dynamically grow need to keep track of?

- A current size.
- An allocated memory size.
- A (pointer to a) chunk of dynamically allocated memory, which can be *reallocated* when the vector needs to grow in size.

One that can store `int` values.

```
typedef struct int_vec {
    size_t sz;
    size_t allocated_sz;
    int *data;
} int_vec_t;
```

When you want to allocate a vector you can use [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to allocate the vector struct, but also the array that the `data` member will point to.

```
int_vec_t *make_int_vec(size_t starting_capacity) {
    int_vec_t *vec = malloc(sizeof(*vec));
    if (!vec) return NULL;

    vec->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * starting_capacity);
    if (!vec->data) {
        free(vec);
        return NULL;
    }

    vec->sz = 0;
    vec->allocated_sz = starting_capacity;

    return vec;
}
```

When you want a vector to *grow* it's best to do this by a factor other than +1. For simplicity, let's use x2. You'd use [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to accomplish this, but in case `realloc` fails, we use a pointer other than `vec->data` to test it so we don't leave the original pointer dangling. Once we know it succeeded we can assign it to `vec->data`.

```
int_vec_t *grow_int_vec(int_vec_t *vec) {
    if (!vec) return NULL;

    int *new_data = realloc(vec->data, sizeof(int) * vec->allocated_sz * 2);
    if (!new_data) return NULL;

    vec->data = new_data;
    vec->allocated_size *= 2;

    return vec;
}
```

Remember on freeing such a structure you need to free the internal array as well. Two `malloc` calls were made to bring this struct into existence, so two `free` calls are needed to destroy it.

```
void free_int_vec(int_vec_t *vec) {
    if (vec) free(vec->data);

    free(vec);
}
```

If we wanted to write a `push_onto_int_vec` function, it might look like the following. A return value of `NULL` indicating that the element was not added, otherwise returning the vector.

```
int_vec_t *push_onto_int_vec(int_vec_t *vec, int val) {
    if (!vec) return NULL;

    if (vec->sz == vec->allocated_sz && !grow_int_vec(vec)) 
        return NULL;
    
    vec->data[vec->sz++] = val;
    return vec;
}
```