# Problem organizing a data set chronologically

Tags: c

I'm here asking for your help, not because I have an error, but simply because of this solution that in my head seemed quite credible despite not working.
I basically have a structure to make an appointment and I created a variable of this temporary structure to change the values ​​so that they are in ascending order, however when I show the query table in this case, but the queries appear in the order I registered them in the program.

My Struct:

```
typedef struct Consulta {

    char nomeUtente[70];
    int numSNS;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int horasInicio;
    int minutosInicio;
    int horasFim;
    int minutosFim;

} consulta;
```

My function that should order the values:

```
void organizarAgenda(int membroEscolhido, consulta agenda[][50][50], int clinicaSelecionada, int *nFuncionarios, int *nAgendas)
{
    
    int i, j;
    boolean substituir;
    consulta temp;

    
    for (i = 0; i < nAgendas[membroEscolhido]; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nAgendas[membroEscolhido]; j++)
    
            if (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano > agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano)
                substituir = true;
                
            if (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano 
            && (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes > agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes))
                substituir = true;
                
            if (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano 
            && (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes)
            && (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia > agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia))
                substituir = true;
                
            if (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano 
            && (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes)
            && (agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia == agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia
            && agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio >= agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio))
                substituir = true;
        
        
            if (substituir == true) 
            {
                
                //Igualar a variavel temporario á variável agenda em i
                temp.ano = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano;
                temp.mes = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes;
                temp.dia = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia;
                temp.horasInicio = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio;
                temp.minutosInicio = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosInicio;
                temp.horasFim = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasFim;
                temp.minutosFim = agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosFim;

                //Igualar a variável agenda em i á variável agenda em j
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosInicio = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosInicio;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasFim = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasFim;
                agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosFim = agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosFim;
                
                //Igualar a variável agenda em j á variavel temporaria
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].ano = temp.ano;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].mes = temp.mes;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia = temp.dia;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasInicio = temp.horasInicio;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosInicio = temp.minutosInicio;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].horasFim = temp.horasFim;
                agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].minutosFim = temp.minutosFim;
                
            }

    }
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Start by simplifying the swap: `consulta temp = agenda[i]; agenda[i] = agenda[j]; agenda[j] = temp;`

Comment: ahaha sorry, i'm new to programming i didn't even know i could do something like that, it makes things a lot easier. But now I'm back to testing and I'm still having the same problem, but it's a strange thing, because every time I click to see the list of queries, that list also changes constantly.

Comment: Write a function to report whether two entries are in date order.  It should take two constant pointers and return a negative value if the first entry comes before the second, a positive value if the first entry comes after the second, and zero if they represent the same time.  Then use that.  You won't need to use 15-18 character array subscript names in the comparator function, which will make it easier to read.  "Meaningful names" are wonderful used carefully, but I think you've gone a little overboard with `membroEscolhido` (15) and `clinicaSelecionada` (18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substituir` is *unitialized*. You need to set it to `false` immediately after the `for` statement for `j`.

Your `for` loop for `j` is missing a trailing `{` so it will only iterate over the *first* `if` and not the others [as you would probably like]

As I mentioned in my comment, *simplify* [please ;-)]. Use pointers to simplify the code.

Your indexing is *quite* complex, so I can only guess at things.

I changed the comparison logic to something I understand.

Here's a simplified version. I *just* coded it, so it may not compile. But, it should give you some ideas how to proceed:

```
typedef struct Consulta {
    char nomeUtente[70];
    int numSNS;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int horasInicio;
    int minutosInicio;
    int horasFim;
    int minutosFim;
} consulta;

void
organizarAgenda(int membroEscolhido, consulta agenda[][50][50],
int clinicaSelecionada, int *nFuncionarios, int *nAgendas)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int lim = nAgendas[membroEscolhido];
    int dif;
    consulta temp;

    for (i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
        consulta *iptr = &agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada];

        for (j = 0; j < lim; j++) {
            consulta *jptr = &agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada];

            do {
                dif = iptr->ano - jptr->ano;
                if (dif)
                    break;

                dif = iptr->mes - jptr->mes;
                if (dif)
                    break;

                dif = iptr->dia - jptr->dia;
                if (dif)
                    break;
            } while (0);

            if (dif <= 0)
                continue;

            temp = *iptr;
            *iptr = *jptr;
            *jptr = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm [still] guessing but I *think* you can get a [significant] speedup by changing the `for` loop for `j`.

And, I think the `for` loop for `i` goes one too far.

So, consider:

```
for (i = 0; i < (lim - 1); i++) {
    consulta *iptr = &agenda[i][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada];

    for (j = i + 1; j < lim; j++) {
        consulta *jptr = &agenda[j][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada];
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I didn't understand how a 3d array with only a 2d array assignment works `int lim = nAgendas[membroEscolhido];`

The value of `nAgendas[membroEscolhido]` is *invariant* across the function, so it can be "cached". I did this to simplify the code [mostly] but it also can help the compiler generate more efficient code.

> I didn't notice the (-) in the middle of this line, and the `->` works because it is a pointer pointing to the `struct`, right?

Right. The arrow operator (`->`) is a very powerful way to access individual `struct` members if you have a pointer to the given struct instance.

Note that the compiler's optimizer *might* be able to see that all the variables of the form: `array[x][y][z].whatever` *could* be reduced.

But, when we use intermediate pointers we're giving it a [better] clue as to what we want. And, the code is more readable by humans, so it has *two* good reasons to do it.

> I don't understand why you put `while (0)`

This is a bit of a trick [of mine] to replace an `if/else` ladder with something that is cleaner.

It forms a "once through" loop. It would be the equivalent of:

```
while (1) {
    if (something)
        break;
    if (something_else)
        break;
    break;  // make the loop execute _only_ once
}
```

For a more detailed explanation, see my answer: [About the exclusiveness of the cases of an if block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656651/about-the-exclusiveness-of-the-cases-of-an-if-block/50685506#50685506)

Comment: Not a problem. I used `https://translate.google.com` to translate your comment. But, unfortunately, I don't understand Portuguese [I'm a native English speaker, but, alas I've only studied French, Russian, and German]. It would be helpful to use English. One of the problems with understanding your code was _not_ knowing what your variable names represented. The `ano`, `mes`, and `dia` were easy enough, but the `membroEscolhido` and `clinicaSelecionada` looked like a joining of two separate words that wouldn't translate too well.

Comment: ahaha I'm sorry for that, now I edit the code with my 
doubts

Comment: I've rejected your edit because it's the not the right way to respond. I've kept the comments and I'll respond. Best way is to add comments here with your concerns. Or, you can _edit_ your question and append the code fragments with comments at the bottom in a separate code block.

Comment: ah ok, sorry for that part too. And I also thank you for all your availability and patience.